# QML: (Linux) Material Design button on deploy not displayed correctly

Tags: qt, qml

On Linux distribution, when I deploy QML application, the button is not displayed correctly.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
Item{

    Button
    {
       text: "Click me"
       Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
       onClicked: console.log("Test")
    }
}
```

When i compile it is shown like this

[image]

But on deploy
I can click on button but it is displayed like this

[image]

Which library am I missing?

PS: I have my own deploy script, which takes output from qmlimportscanner and find qml libs.

Comment: You likely are missing the QML style plugins.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I will try it.